# JQuery.ajax() makes a copy of the settings object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

[JQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) accepts a `settings` argument. The functions for `success` or `error` (for example) run in the context of this object.

```
var arr = [];
var a = {
    url : '/',
    arbiteraryProperty: 'yeah!',
    complete:function () {
        console.dir(arr[0]);
    }
};

arr.push( a );

$.ajax( a );
```

runs the command and then prints the attributes of the first element of arr (which is a) as follows:

> ```
> arbiteraryProperty : "yeah!"
> url : "/"
> complete : function()
> ```

Now the problem is that the `this` keyword inside the above `complete` function is not actually referring to the `settings` object. It is interesting because it seems JQuery is making a copy of the `settings` object.

```
var arr = [];
var a = {
    url : '/',
    arbiteraryProperty: 'yeah!',
    complete:function () {
        console.log(this.arbiteraryProperty );
        //this prints 'yeah!'
        this.arbiteraryProperty = 'nope!';
        console.log( this.arbiteraryProperty );
        //this prints 'nope!' so the value of the attribute in this is changed
        console.log( a.arbiteraryProperty );
        //this prints 'yeah!' ie. the value originally existed in the settings object
    }
};

arr.push( a );

$.ajax( a );
```

The question is: does JQuery really create a duplicate copy of the setting object? And if yes, how can I force it to use my object?

I have an application where I need to save these objects in a queue and expect them to be updated when they run. I guess one alternative is to use the `context` settings for the `$.ajax()`. However this behavior of this function (making a copy of the settings object) wasn't documented. Or I missed it?

Comment: Any object within that struct will probably be referenced (can't be sure; it might be a deep copy). If so, it means you could do `{context:{variable:3},complete:function(){this.context.variable=2}}`.

Comment: You can just make one of the properties (like `arbiteraryProperty`) point to your object in the queue that needs to be updated, as you can see you still can access it from the copied object.

Comment: @Dave Isn't the whole point of the `context` property to change what `this` refers to? So it would just be `this.variable`, not `this.context.variable`.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist oh, right, I didn't realise `context` was special. I was just suggesting a random name, like `{yippie:{variable:3}}`, so that there was a persistent data store. But yeah, I guess `context` itself could achieve similar results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, jQuery creates a new options object when you call `jQuery.ajax()`. The result is a combination of the settings object you passed and the global `jQuery.ajaxSettings` object, so that you have the correct default values and any settings you've set globally, even when you don't explicitly set them in the object passed.

This can be seen in the [source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js) for jQuery 1.9 on line 7745:

```
// Create the final options object
s = jQuery.ajaxSetup( {}, options ),
```

Generally you use the `context` property to specify a different value for `this` inside the callback functions, so:

```
options = {
    url: '/',
    ...,
    context: a
}
```

However, the circular reference in your case (`a` referring to itself in one of its properties) may cause issues if the merge does a deep copy.

Comment: I don't believe it would do a deep copy, because if it did, it would render the `context` useless in most cases.

Comment: a) It does make a deep copy, but excludes specific properties like `context` from this. Search for `ajaxextend` and `flatoptions` in the source b) The OP doesn't have a circular reference in his example, `arr` is not a property of `a`.